# error FUNCTION test.OBJECT_ID does not exist when I try to connect my web api to my sql

Tags: c#, mysql, webapi, objectid

> PM> dotnet ef database update Build started... Build succeeded. info:
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
> Executed DbCommand (56ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> SELECT 1 fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]'); Failed executing DbCommand (19ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
> CommandTimeout='30'] SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): FUNCTION test.OBJECT_ID
> does not exist    at
> MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior
> ioBehavior) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 43    at
> MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line
> 130    at
> MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition
> commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator,
> IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 468    at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1
> commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior
> behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56    at
> MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalarAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 316    at
> MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() in
> /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 110    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteScalar(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
> targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
> action) FUNCTION test.OBJECT_ID does not exist PM>

what could be the problem ?

I am using .net core 6 , and xxamp for the mysql interface .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unreadable. Format properly.